# "Как раз что надо" — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Написал такую фразу:

> Чашки по объёму оказались в самый раз что мне надо.

Не хочется ставить запятые. Это правильно и как обосновать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Чашки по объёму оказались в самый раз что мне надо.***

Фраза  выглядит некорректно. Какие тут проблемы?

1. Глагол «оказались»  – это связка,  он обычно управляет Т.п или И.п. существительного, прилагательного, местоимения.  Если использовать  после «оказались» устойчивое сочетание, то оно должно быть компактным, с минимальной распространенностью.  Кроме того,  желательно включить в него местоимение ТО (И.п.)
2. Дополнение «мне» не лучшим образом влияет на устойчивость сочетания.
3. Выражения «в самый раз»  и  «как раз»  могут быть синонимами, при этом у них две функции: предикатив или  усилительное слово. При наличии связки  это только усилительное слово (именно, точно), в этом случае  «как раз»  более уместно для образования устойчивого сочетания.

Поэтому можно предложить два варианта.

(1) ***Чашки по объёму оказались как раз то что надо.***  Здесь использовано местоимение «то»  после связки. Сравнить (из Нацкорпуса): Катер оказался то что надо.

(2) ***Чашки по объёму оказались походящими,  в самый раз что мне надо.***
Здесь  устойчивое сочетание в функции второго предикатива, требования к нему минимальные.

К предложенным литературным вариантам  в первом ответе тоже есть вопросы.

(1) *Чашки по объёму оказались как раз что надо.* Желательно  использовать местоимение «то» для сочетаемости со связкой.

(2) *Чашки по объёму оказались как раз такими, что мне надо.* Союзное слово ЧТО заменяет союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ, а здесь союзное слово КАКОЙ. Лучше сказать: Чашки по объёму оказались как раз такими, какие мне нужны.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Конец последней фразы я бы только переделал на "какие мне нужны".

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено. Хорошее  чувство языка, Артем, с ошибками  у вас не забалуешь.  Но вот "на переулке" вам  категорически не нравится.  Неужели ничего  позитивного нет в  этом ненормированном употреблении предлога НА?

Comment: :) Я буду только рад, если вы мне покажете позитивные моменты этого употребления и измените моё отношение к этому. ;) Я потому и спрашиваю, что не выработал чёткой позиции или отношения к этому вопросу.

Comment: Да? А мне показалось, что  всё уже решено (буду относиться плохо, как и раньше относился). Вот когда вам верить, не знаю, но всё-таки подумаю над вашим вопросом.

Comment: Ха-ха, верьте всегда)) Просто Галина меня склонила к тому, чтобы плохо относиться и дальше, но я же всегда могу передумать, изменить своё отношение! Я не из таких, кто считает, что Baskin и Robins братья, это их имена и всё тут! Даже авторитетные источники таких упрямых не могут переубедить. Попалась сегодня такая тётка)) Не догадался спросить, какая же (по её мнению) у них была фамилия. :))

Comment: Наверно, лучше было "не из **тех,** кто считает", да? Перечитал и подумал, что кому-то может это не понравиться.

Answer (score 3):

Артём, если б у Вас была фраза, которую Вы указали в заголовке вопроса - “Как раз что надо” — никаких разногласий бы не было: это фразеологизм *что надо = отличный*, но ведь у Вас на самом деле другая фраза:

> Чашки по объёму оказались в самый раз что мне надо.

Фраза, надо сказать, не совсем литературная: то ли здесь избыточность, повтор (в самый раз и есть то, что мне надо),тогда запятая нужна, то ли *в самый раз* употреблено вместо частицы *как раз* (Чашки по объёму оказались как раз что мне надо), тогда запятой нет, потому что **оказались что мне надо** вместе с частицей является сказуемым, слитным сочетанием.

Литературная фраза должна бы звучать так:

*Чашки по объёму оказались как раз такими, что мне надо* (запятая перед придаточным).

Или: *Чашки по объёму оказались как раз что надо* (нет запятой перед фразеологизмом в составе сказуемого — слитного сочетания).

А вот в том виде, что у Вас есть, это Вам решать, что Вы имели в виду - союзное слово пропустили или "в самый раз" употребили вместо "как раз".

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Да, я употребил "в самый раз" вместо "как раз". А можно так: "оказались в самый раз такими, что мне надо"? Чтобы подчеркнуть, что совсем подошли, ярче это выразить.

Comment: Да, так корректно(но всё равно это разговорное выражение, разговорное ярче, выразительнее) и пунктуация  без всяких вопросов

Comment: Понятно, Людмила, спасибо! Может быть, попрошу изменить эту мою фразу (на Авито в отзыве написал).

Comment: Ну, там не обязательно что-то менять, и так пойдёт, зачем их загружать тем, на что никто не обратит внимания?

Comment: Тоже правильно! Не буду. :)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не ставится, потому что это цельный по смыслу оборот, не образующей придаточной части. "Что мне надо" можно заменить на дополнение "для меня", смысл не изменится.

> Чашки по объёму оказались в самый раз для меня.

Таким образом, можно считать, что это простое предложение с **цельным по смыслу сочетанием**.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm#%D0%B7_01

> Цельные по смыслу выражения не выделяются знаками препинания.
>
> **Запятая не ставится** **перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом** в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: сделать как следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно), хватать что подвернется, явиться как ни в чем не бывало, говорить что в ум взбредёт, добиваться во что бы то ни стало...
> Данное правило основано на том, что **фразеологические обороты не образуют придаточного предложения и**, как правило, **эквивалентны члену предложения**. Так, в сочетании говорит об этом где только может последние слова имеют значение «везде».